# How to mock a fetch call that is within an arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, testing, fetch

I'm trying to test the invocation of a function that deletes specific data saved in a database in React. The problem is I want to only mock the fetch call and have everything else run as usual because right now whenever tests are run the data gets deleted in the database.

Here is my code for the delete function:

```
deleteEvent = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch(
        "api url",
        {
          method: "DELETE",
        }
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log(result);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    this.props.history.push("/eventList");
  };
```

And here is my test code:

```
test("deleteEvent function works", (done) => {
  const mockSuccessResponse = {};
  const mockJsonPromise = Promise.resolve(mockSuccessResponse);
  const mockFetchPromise = Promise.resolve({
    json: () => mockJsonPromise,
  });
  jest.spyOn(global, "fetch").mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);

  const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };
  const wrapper = shallow(<EventState history={historyMock} />);
  wrapper.instance().deleteEvent();
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(["/eventList"]);
  global.fetch.mockClear();
  done();
});
```

I get number times called: 0 for the expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
and a Received: undefined for the expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(["/eventList"]);

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `spyOn(global, fetch)`, try this:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);

  const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };
  const wrapper = shallow(<EventState history={historyMock} />);
  wrapper.instance().deleteEvent();
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(["/eventList"]);
  global.fetch.mockClear();
  done();
});
```

Comment: I tried that. That only seems to work with export functions whereas mine is located within a class component.

Comment: I have updated the answer to something that should work

Comment: instead of `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);` try
`jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockFetchPromise);`

Comment: I was actually able to pass the expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); line by switching deleteEvent() to deleteEvent since i'm using an arrow function but the expect(historyMock.push.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(["/eventList"]); still fails and gets an undefined and i'm not sure why

Comment: try `const historyMock = jest.fn(()=>({push: jest.fn()}))`

Comment: Actually you're above code works I had a misplaced a variable name lol. Thank you for the help

Comment: actually sorry this doesn't work if deleteEvent is an async function. I've also tried putting async beside the (done) in the test and it still fails. Any ideas?